# Linux: Browsers has no hardware acceleration Nvidia 840M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.10, browser, hardware-acceleration

My laptop has a nvidia 840m geforce card. I'm trying to get hardware acceleration working for youtube on the browser.

As the cpu heats up.

After spending much time going through forums and guides. I found out that `vdpau` is not even enabled.

The result of `vdpauinfo` and `vaainfo` is below:

```
$ vdpauinfo

display: :1   screen: 0
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
Error creating VDPAU device: 1

$ vainfo

libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 1):

A lot of laptops with NVIDIA GPUs also have onboard Intel graphics. You might want to check that you're currently using the NVIDIA GPU and not the Intel one. nvidia-settings should show you which PRIME profile you are currently using.

I believe there's a `prime-select` or `bumblebee` utility to switch between the GPUs.

Comment: in Prime Profile, I have selected Nvidia Performances. 

By right, vainfo or vdpauinfo should detect the card. My card supports it.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEYPJ.png